# Symfony form view guess wrong method?

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony 5, and i've created 3 classes Deal, DealCategory and DealSubCategory with `php bin/console make:entity`.
These are relation between these classes.

Here is the gist of these classes

https://gist.github.com/methodeprog/8ca704f89910284197e93cafb1f009de

Then after php bin/console `make:crud` of them

In Deal Form, when try to create a Deal, i got this.
This is very weird please help

```
Neither the property "dealCategory" nor one of the methods "dealCategory()", "getdealCategory()"/"isdealCategory()"/"hasdealCategory()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".
```

That is weird is that in my Deal class methods there is not getdealCategory() but getDealCategory()...

Why Symfony suggest `getdealCategory()` instead of `getDealCategory()` ?

Comment: @JessGabriel, i reopend the question, i think its more clear now

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your code of formType file and controller addAction ?

I think you forget in your DealType :

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
  'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Deal' 
));
```

Hope this help

Comment: Really this help me, error his just above, ive use multiple addEventListener with addElements2...with onPreSubmit2 with $this->addElements($form, $dealCategory); instead of $this->addElements2($form, $dealCategory);...Great thank @threeside